# Atom won't autocomplete HTML

Tags: html, autocomplete, atom-editor

I don't why? but atom editor won't autocomplete tags (not all of them) like when I type input it won't even detect it and if I type < input > it won't close it

on the other hand, it autocompletes the div tags to

```html
<div class="">

</div>
```

Can someone please help me fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Install and try [`autocomplete-html-entities`](https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-html-entities). It provides extra functionality for HTML alongside [`autocomplete-plus`](https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-plus) installed by default.